# Is MongoDB always write to primary Shard and then rebalance?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

```
use vsm;
sh.enableSharding('vsm');
sh.shardCollection('vsm.pricelist', {maker_id:1});
```

Ok, we enabled sharding for Database (vsm) and collection in this database (pricelist).

We trying to write about 80 million documents to 'pricelist' collection.
And we have about 2000 distributed uniformly different maker_ids.

We have three shards. And Shard002 is PRIMARY for 'vsm' database.

We write to 'pricelist' collection from four application nodes with started mongos on each.

And during write data to 'pricelist' collection we see CPU Usage 100% **ONLY** on Shard002 !

We see rebalancing process. And data migrate to Shard000 and Shard003. But Shard002 has hight CPU Usage and Load Average!

Shards deployed on c4.xlarge EBS Optimized instances. dbdata stored on io1 with 2000 IOPS EBS Volumes.

It is looks like MongoDB write data only to one Shard :( What we do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Is MongoDB always write to primary Shard and then rebalance?

***Yes, if you are relying on auto balancer. And loading huge amounts of data into an empty collection***

In your situation, you are relying on the autobalancer to do all the sharding / balancing stuff. I assume what you require is, as your data gets loaded it goes to each shard during load hence having less CPU usage etc.

This how sharding / autobalancing will take place on a high level.

- Create chunks of data using split http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/split/
- Move the chunks to other shards http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/moveChunk/#dbcmd.moveChunk

Now, when autobalancer is ON these two steps occur when your data is already loaded or loading.

***Solution***

- Create empty collection. Execute the shard command on it. The collection where your data is going to get loaded.
- Turn off the auto balancer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#disable-the-balancer
- Manually create empty chunks using split. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/
- Move those empty chunks to different shards. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/migrate-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/
- Start the load, This time all your data should go directly to their respective shards.
- **Turn ON the balancer.** (Once the load is complete) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#enable-the-balancer

You will have to test this approach using a small data set first. But I guess I have got enough information for you to get started.

Comment: Plainly wrong. Mongos will write the data directly to the shard to which key range a document belongs to. When all data is written to a single shard, this is the perfect indication for monotonically increasing shard key, as `ObjectId`, for example.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - I am not sure about what you said. See this text in the question "We see rebalancing process. And data migrate to Shard000 and Shard003." this clearly explains that the re-balancing is going on. Also, lets consider that the shard key is good enough and I start loading some huge data on a empty collection. Data will still go into 1 primary shard unless you do presplitting and manual chunk moving.

Comment: Your statement that writes *always* go to the primary shard when using the autobalancer is [plainly wrong, as clearly stated by the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/distributed-write-operations/#write-operations-on-sharded-clusters). Simplified: the balancing process will assign new key ranges when the migration threshold is reached. After a shard is assigned a key range, writes concerning that key range are directly routed to that shard. If the shard key was good, the writes would be distributed after a while. This doesn't happen, so with the fewest assumption the key is bad. q.e.d.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg My statement is not wrong. You have to think about it on a context. If we are putting in loads of data into an empty collection then it will always go to the primary shard as there are no partitions / chunks present. Please go thru the top few points here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/#create-chunks-in-a-sharded-cluster . I have also edited my answer a bit to make it more clear. Also the answer was in the context of the question, it was not a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

What you describe is usually the indication that you have chosen a [poor shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) with `makerid`, most likely monotonically increasing.

What usually happens is that one shard is assigned the key range from `x` to `infinity` (shard002 in your case). Now all new documents get written to that shard, until that shards holds more chunks in excess of the current [migration threshold](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/#migration-thresholds). Now the balancer kicks in and moves some chunks. Problem is that new documents *still* get written to said shard.

### The solution

An easy solution for that problem is to [use hashed keys for sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/)

Now here comes the serious problem: you can not change the shard key.

So what you have to do is to make a backup of the sharded collection, drop it, reshard the collection using the hashed `makerId` and restore the backup into the new collection.